# tkinter ttk style In tkinter, I want to make my label appear

Tags: python, tkinter

I created new style frame using ttk.style
And I made the frame appear with image.
but a label doesn't appear on the frame.

Here is my code:

```
root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
img = tk.PhotoImage(file="img/line_test.png")
style.element_create("teststyle.TFrame", "image", img)
style.configure("teststyle.TFrame", background="red", compound="center")
style.layout("teststyle.TFrame", [("teststyle.TFrame", {"sticky": "nsew"})])
frame = ttk.Frame(root, style="teststyle.TFrame", height=100, width=360)
test_lbl = ttk.Label(frame, text="test", style="teststyle.TFrame")
test_lbl.pack()
frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You use a Frame style for a Label so the text will not be displayed since Frame's layout does not have a label element.

Comment: I want to make a frame with rounded border, and put some elements(entry, label, button) insde. Can I do it?? if I use teststyle not teststlye.TFrame???

Comment: What I wanted to say is don't change the style option of the Label, just put it in the frame. If you want to see your rounded borders, you might need to increase the frame padding though.

Comment: So, you mean // test_lbl = ttk.Label(frame, text="test") // test_lbl(pack) ~~~~???

Comment: Yes, because you want to change the style of the frame, not the label right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to apply the style to both the frame and the label inside your frame. You should not be using the custom style for the label widget.

The problem is that the layout specifies which internal elements appear for the widget and how they are organized. A scrollbar has a trough and a thumb and a border. Buttons have text elements and borders, a Label has a border and a text element, etc. Your frame layout only has a border, it doesn't have a text element. Thus, any text associated with the widget won't show.

You need to remove the style from the label widget:

```
test_lbl = ttk.Label(frame, text="test")
```